# Validation of clustering results through correlation maps

Tags: correlation, clustering

How can I compare correlation maps independently to the number of clusters in terms of  measuring the 'quality' of well separating (uncorrelated) clusters, i.e. a criterion to maximize the intra-cluster agreement and the inter-cluster disagreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with correlation map you mean a matrix graph similar to [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Correlation_matrix/) but then with actual correlation values displayed as well. I also assume that by cluster you mean the result of a regression or classification tree/algorithm. If you are asking how to maximize the intra-cluster agreement and the inter-cluster disagreement, that is what a pruned regression tree would do for you automatically with a penalty for complexity (without the penalty every observation would have its own terminal node). This is usually done by minimizing a cost function like $\Sigma{RSS_k}+\lambda|k|$ where there are $k$ terminal nodes. Have a look at libraries like `rpart` in R.

Here I assume you are asking how to quantify the difference between the result from your clusters in a regression tree and the correlation matrix you have. I do not know if there is a formal answer for that but here is an idea:

You can combine the concept of a Gini index with Euclidean distance to give you a measure that should be comparable to the observed correlation. Whether you are validating cluster results through correlation maps or vice versa is a matter of interpretation (if you are using pearson correlation it will also give you a measure of non-linear covariance in the data).

Let us say you are looking at $m$ correlated series of data for which you ran a regression tree. Take every terminal node $k$ and determine what proportion of series $i$ is in the node. Call it $p_{ik}$. Determine this for every $i$ and you will get a vector $v_i$ of length $k$ whose sum will equal 1. Get the $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ euclidean distances between the $m$ vectors $v_i$ and they should be comparable with the $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ correlations you have. As the Euclidean distance goes to zero, the correlation should go to 1 (that is not a proven fact and probably only true in an approximate sense).

Comment: I guess you could further improve on it by transforming the vectors to norm 1. That way the euclidean distance is [0,2] and the correlation is [-1,1].

Comment: I would like to see someone critique this approach because it seems like there should be some flaws here - apart from the absolute lack of formalism that is.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to assign a quality index to each of two different correlation maps, which would probably have not the same number of rows-columns (e.g. mxm vs nxn), in order to decide the preferable clustering which is reflected by each of the correlation maps. For example,  the Correlation Clustering functional (CC) might be useful: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~meirav/Bagon_Galun_LargeScaleCorrClust_2011.pdf

Comment: Looking at the CC paper you cite, I assume you want to do this because your data set is humungous. Because if you only care about relatively small data sets, in-sample minimization of the variance in sub-clusters and maximization of variance between sub-clusters is what a simple regression tree does. If you care about out of sample performance you can have a look at random forests.